# How to find the correlation between scatter data and theoretical formula MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, correlation, scatter-plot

I'm working on my thesis project on financial mathematics. One problem I'm having is that I want to find out if there is some correlation between a theoretical curve and scatter point data.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709705/Conditional%20probability%20of%20an%20upward%20move%20DATA2.png) is the scatter data and the theoretical curve that I have.

Is there some easy way of doing this?

Comment: here perhaps some ideas: [Evaluating Goodness of Fit](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/curvefit/bq_6zzm.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bivariate correlation (usually Pearson correlation) is a statistic that measures linear dependence between two sets of data. The theoretical curve of [your link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709705/Conditional%20probability%20of%20an%20upward%20move%20DATA2.png) does not seem to consist of discrete data points, therefore it is not possible to calculate correlation between it a and some set of data.

Depending on the model and the research question you have, you might be interested in analyzing the fit of your data to the model, using multivariate regression analysis or general[ized] linear model. These MATLAB commands could be useful: `regress` ([multiple linear regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/regress.html)), `regstats` ([regression diagnostics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/regstats.html)), `glmfit` ([generalized linear model regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/glmfit.html)) and `glmval` ([generalized linear model values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/glmval.html)).

Comment: Good suggestions! But it is possible to take out discrete points of the theoretical curve. Couldn't I then calculate the bivariate correlation?

Comment: Well, yes, but if you have more than one variable on either side, bivariate correlation does not make sense, because x, y & z probably are not independent, but depend on each other (if they do correlate with each other). But you could also use canonical correlation (same as canonical analysis) in which you could have measured x, y & z variables on one side and theoretical predicted (discrete data points) x, y & z variables on the other side. In MATLAB there is `canoncorr` command for [canonical correlation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/canoncorr.html) .

Comment: Thanks! Canonical correlation is the way to go for me! :)